# Tracking Maxymiser with DTM

Tags: adobe-analytics

Is there a way to track maxymiser data in Adobe analytics using DTM (Dynamic Tag Management)? The site is using Maxymiser for serving personalized content dynamically and we want to track what personalized content was served? Is it possible to track it with DTM?

Comment: DTM doesn't track anything. It provides a way to host and deploy tags. So DTM doesn't really play a part in any kind of Maxymiser>AA integration, other than potentially hosting some integration code in it, depending on if you have one or both of Maxymiser/AA implemented in DTM.  The long story short is you need to talk to Maxymiser to have them output the campaign/recipe/variation code to an adobe variable (e.g. an `eVar`)

Comment: http://www.attacklowhangingfruit.com/web-analytics/adobe-analytics/integrating-maxymiser-into-adobe-sitecataylst  is kind of old but still basically relevant.

Comment: @CrayonViolent: Thanks for your answer! AA is implemented via DTM. Maxymiser & AA integration is in place and was working earlier but since we recently moved to DTM so that integration is no longer valid and not populating the evar in Adobe RS. What changes do we need to make on Maxymiser end to make it work. Do we need to have them embed the DTM script tags?